# attach a JWT token to api request via angular 4

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, typescript, jwt

I'm building an Angular app, with ASP.NET Core 2.0 back-end. I have successfully implemented JWT login and it works fine. Now, following the tutorial located [here](https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors), I'm trying to fetch data for resources requiring authorization via JWT. I used postman to verify that this works when I use the token to make the HTTP get.

In my angular app, I receive 401. I use the visual studio 2017 angular template app for my sample app. Everything else works, I can login, when my token expires, I'm requested to login again so all those aspects work. I'm just missing the last part. 
The server api call is as follow:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    private static string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index).ToString("d"),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        });
    }

    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF
        {
            get
            {
                return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The angular component has the following code:

```
    import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'fetchdata',
    templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
            this.forecasts = result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}
```

[image]

Here is the code that adds the authorization header:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
//import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from "@angular/http/http";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was here:

```
   Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
```

The getToken method was returning the entire Token object. Instead, as someone pointed out on another thread, i had to explicitly extract the actual token string as follow:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

So this is very simple, the tutorial you posted used angualar-jwt (which I have used myself).

They provide their own wrapper for the http service that sends a saved JWT token as part of the request to your (or someone else's) API endpoint.

If its someone else's API just make sure you change the header prefix to match that of where they are expecting a JWT token.

From the angular2-jwt readme:

If you wish to only send a JWT on a specific HTTP request, you can use the AuthHttp class. This class is a wrapper for Angular 2's Http and thus supports all the same HTTP methods.

```
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
// ...
class App {

thing: string;

constructor(public authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

getThing() {
    this.authHttp.get('http://example.com/api/thing')
    .subscribe(
        data => this.thing = data,
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you look at the tutorial, they have a Ping component that uses the new HttpClient class to fetch the data. This should therefore work without using your approach

Comment: I have updated the question the code of the interceptor. It automatically appends any token to the authorization header, hence no additional work should be required

Answer (score -1):

you can pass options parameters to your http get method, check out here
https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptionsArgs